# Custom conditional scoped mutex lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

I am making a custom Conditional Scoped Mutex Lock.

I have this class defined in my header:

```
class ConditionalLock
{
public:
    ConditionalLock(eastl::function<bool()> condition);
    ~ConditionalLock();

private:        
    static std::mutex s_mtx;
    static bool s_shouldLock;
    static bool s_lockInit;
};
```

.cpp looks like this:

```
ConditionalLock::ConditionalLock(std::function<bool()> condition)
{
    if (!s_lockInit)
    {
        if (condition())
            s_shouldLock = true;

        s_lockInit = true;
    }

    if (s_shouldLock)
        s_mtx.Lock();
}

ConditionalLock::~ConditionalLock()
{
    if (s_shouldLock)
        s_mtx.Unlock();
}
```

This conditional lock does the trick if I use it in only one place, concerning the fact that it contains three static members that track everything I need. 
However, I want to have a generic conditioned mutex that could be reused everywhere. What would be the right approach?

I thought about making a ConditionalMutexContext class that would be instantiated in the scope of the object where I want to use this mutex, and  that config would contain these properties.

Something like this:

```
class ConditionalLockContext 
{
public:
    ConditionalLockContext(
        std::function<bool()> condition)
    : m_condition(condition)

private: 
    std::function<bool()> m_condition;
    bool m_shouldLock;
    bool m_lockInit;
}
```

And then pass the ConditionalLockContext instance to the conditional lock by reference.

Could you think of a better approach for this specific scenario?

Comment: i dont really get it, why are those members `static` in the first place?

Comment: It's a scoped mutex so the object gets destroyed when it goes out of scope and I want to keep everything related to this mutex so that I can reuse it in a bunch of places.

Comment: ok, and why are those members `static` ?

Comment: Because I don't want to interact with the mutex or any logic when using this lock. I want to be able to initialize this on stack without thinking about which mutex is being locked etc. If I use statics I maintain the context through multiple instances of the conditional mutex class. If I define a context class and just instantiate it and pass it to the conditional mutex class I get some sort of elegance I wanted to have.

Comment: void fnc() 
{ 
ConditionalMutex([](){ return true; }) }

Comment: tbh I still dont really understand it, but maybe this can help you: make the class a template to enable having different instantiations, either use an index, or you can pass a lambda as tag, then every instantiation is of different type and has its own `static` members

Comment: i find it rather questionable to write `void fnc() { ConditionalMutex([](){ return true; }) }` and trying to hide which mutex is being locked in that line, but as I already said, I dont really understand it

Comment: Thought about that already, might do the trick. It should affect the compile time only so it should be fine. I need as much performance as possible so I am careful about using too many abstractions.Thanks!

Comment: i think what you should reconsider is "without thinking about which mutex is being locked". How do you not write completely obfuscated code, when its not clear from the code what mutex is being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing mutexes with locks. In C++, we implement RAII locking via (scoped) locks, mutexes do not have this behavior; look at [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex).

You want to implement a conditional scoped lock (derive from [`std::unique_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock), perhaps?). The state whether it locked something is separated from the state of the mutex.

In any case, I do not see a reason of having a shared state between *all* mutex instances, because that is exactly what `static` means... On the other hand, a mutex should be shared by lock instances, but *not* all of them. Thus, you want locks to *refer* to mutexes.

If you do not want to derive from `std::unique_lock` (`private`-ly, of course), **remove all `static` specifiers**, and change the member mutex so that it is a **reference** that is provided during the construction of the lock.

Comment: I will accept this as an answer as I think std::unique_lock will do the trick, combined with conditional variables